# Disable INFO logs in aws kcl - Kinesis

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kcl, amazon-kinesis-kpl

I'm running on `Ubuntu 16.04` & `Java 8`. `kcl` generate thousands of `INFO` log lines.
Does any one know how to enable only `ERROR` and `WARN` logs?

*I have also the same question for `kpl`.

---

I don't have a logfile.

Comment: You disable using your application logging config, which you have not described.

Comment: I dont have one. But how do I disable logs only from specific lib? Can you please provide an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<configuration>
    .........

    <logger name="com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer" level="warn"/>
    <logger name="com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.clientlibrary" level="warn"/>

    .........
</configuration>
```

Log levels: https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/apache/commons/logging/Log.html.
You can also define a prefix of packages.

Comment: should be com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer instead of com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.proucer (Misspelled)

Comment: Where and which file needs to be configured?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember. it was a long time ago. I think it is the logger configuration file, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the V2 AWS SDK/KCL libraries, consider the following.

Put this in your logging config file:

```
<logger name="software.amazon.kinesis" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="io.netty.handler" level="INFO"/>
```

or use this to reduce the full AWS SDK debug logs:

```
<logger name="software.amazon" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="io.netty.handler" level="INFO"/>
```

Either way, this will reduce the output significantly.